# Special characters in outputStream

Tags: java, android, outputstream

I have an application that prints cashing tickets, so I have to print characters like "€" or accents. I tried many things but not print these characters.

Like this:

```
String msg = ConfLogicielCentral.getEnteteTicket() + "\n";

        for (int i = 0 ; i < listItem.size() ; i++ )
        {
            msg += "\n Numero de ticket : \t\t" + listItem.get(i).get("noTicket") ;
            msg += "\n Nom du marché : " + listItem.get(i).get("nomMarch");
            msg += "\n \n Total du marche: \t\t" + listItem.get(i).get("Total");
            msg += "\n" ;
            msg += "****************************** \n" ;
        }

        msg += "\n \t Bilan Total : " + total.getText() ;
        msg += "\n****************************** \n" ;
        msg += "\n\n";
        msg += ConfLogicielCentral.getPiedTicket() ;
        msg += "\n" + "\n" +"\n" +"\n" +"\n" +"\n" + "\n";

        mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
        mmOutputStream.flush();
```

If someone could help me, a big thank you to him

ps: sorry for my english

Comment: So, you are sending them encoded using the ISO-8859-1 encoding. What encoding does the receiving side expect? Is this indeed ISO-8859-1 or a different encoding? Find out what the receiving side expects and use the correct character encoding.

Comment: There's no `€` character in ISO-8859-1. Use an encoding that the receiving end supports and is able to encode all characters you're transmitting.

Comment: A print of the characters I have that I have not even on my keyboard instead of "é" and "€"

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape the characters and to replace them in your message before setting it to the outputWriter? for example

```
msg.replaceAll("€","\u20ac"); //or with its' html code (&euro;) http://character-code.com/currency-html-codes.php
```

Comment: and did you try to replace the ISO-8859-1 with UTF-8 after you replaced the special characters?

Comment: Not always working? When is it working and when not?

Comment: Oops sorry for my english, your solution not work and has never worked (for now)

Comment: Try with this `String data = "MARIE-HÉLÈNE";`
     `byte sByte[] = data.getBytes("UTF-8");`
      `data = new String(sByte,"UTF-8");`
      `System.out.println(data);`
It works for special characters, maybe you didn't try with UTF-8 properly

Comment: This does not work, I have strange characters in place of accents

Answer (score 0):

If in your process the line "mmOutputStream.flush();" is not indispensable, delete and treat, that work for me.